# How do I reveal an optional field in a Django form, when a checkbox is checked?

Tags: python, django, forms

Is this possible with Django, without using Javascript?

Answer (score 4):

It is technically possible using some CSS3 techniques, although there won't be universal browser support.

Your field will have an id depending upon the form's prefix ('id' by default, configurable when creating a form), so you can style a form element in css with the identifier #id_field_name. Then you can use some [CSS3 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) to get to your fields, something like this:

```
#id_checkbox_field ~ #id_hidden_field {display: none; }
#id_checkbox_field[checked] ~ #id_hidden_field { display: block; }
```

Of course, your selector will vary depending upon your document structure. The tilda will only work if `id_checkbox_field` and `id_hidden_field` share a parent, but you can theoretically set up your document structure so that this can be done with CSS3. If you want smooth animations, it's [technically possible](http://www.westciv.com/tools/transforms/index.html), but not easy and not well supported.

The alternative, as pjmorse said, is to have them check the box, submit the form, and have it come back with the new field displayed. Let me know if you want help figuring that out, it's a whole nother can of worms, and I doubt it's what you're looking for.

Most of the time, when you want to do something dynamically, you want to use javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Submitting the form is not an option. You confirm that I did not overlook a Django option. To stay away from javascript, not because I'am afraid of it, I'll skip the checkbox and show an optional field.

Comment: Good idea. Frameworks like Django are for server-side code,and can't affect a page at all once the client gets it. Django only helps you respond to requests such as page submissions or asynchronous javascript and xml (ajax). If you want anything to happen to the page after it's loaded, you need to use javascript or wait until CSS3 has better support. :)

Answer (score 2):

You mean reveal an optional field when the checkbox is checked? That's close to impossible in any framework without Javascript. Your simple options are either to use JS to reveal the optional field depending on the state of the checkbox, or make the checkbox actually post back to reload a different version of the form showing the optional field (and making the checkbox behave that way would require JS).

I imagine it might be possible to wrangle something together with CSS, but JS would actually be more reliable - and you might still need it to change the selectors of a container view.